# Multiple databases with eve

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, neo4j, swagger, eve

I am new to eve and did not use it yet, but it looks very promising as I like flask a lot.

What would be the best way to go, when I try to work on multiple different databases (mongodb, elasticsearch and neo4j).

Would it be best to start several eve services as mentioned over here?
https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/848

Or is there yet a way to configure it, like for multiple mongodb instances?
http://python-eve.org/config.html

I like to avoid multiple eves as I also want to generate one swagger api.

So what would be a good way to go in that case?

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for multiple datastore types served from a single Eve instance. You should go the other way around.